# Get maximum workgroup size for compute shaders?

Tags: android, opengl-es, compute-shader

I am writing an OpenGL ES 3.1 program and want to know the maximum workgroup size for the device I'm running on (its running on Android 6).

For PC querying `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT` and `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` works fine, but I cant seem to do the equivalent for on Android, I get `OpenGL error: InvalidEnum` when I try something like

OpenTK code:

```
int[] work_grp_cnt = new int[3];
GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupCount, work_grp_cnt);
```

Same with native Android APIs:

```
int[] work_grp_cnt = new int[3];
IntBuffer maxCount = IntBuffer.Allocate(3);
GLES20.GlGetIntegerv(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupCount, maxCount);
maxCount.Get(work_grp_cnt);
```

(in both cases the GLGetInteger raises the same InvalidEnum error) 
Is this possible with OpenGL ES 3.1?
I am using a Sony Xperia Z5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you must call `glGetIntegeri_v`, which takes an index. For `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT`, the index is the dimension you want to query. It only returns one value at a time.

You will need to find and use the Java-equivalent of this function.

Comment: I've added the Java equivalent of my function, its the same error. Also the error is on the OpenGL side, which makes me think that I am calling the wrong API, not that my syntax is wrong as you suggested.

Comment: That's not the same function. The "i_" part is important.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I posted the working code as another answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @NicolBoas pointed out I called the wrong function. Heres the working code:

OpenTK:

```
        GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 0, out work_grp_cnt[0]);
        GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 1, out work_grp_cnt[1]);
        GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 2, out work_grp_cnt[2]);

        GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 0, out work_grp_size[0]);
        GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 1, out work_grp_size[1]);
        GL.GetInteger(All.MaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 2, out work_grp_size[2]);
```

Native Android:

```
        GLES31.GlGetIntegeri_v(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 0, work_grp_cnt, 0);
        GLES31.GlGetIntegeri_v(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 1, work_grp_cnt, 1);
        GLES31.GlGetIntegeri_v(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 2, work_grp_cnt, 2);

        GLES31.GlGetIntegeri_v(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 0, work_grp_size, 0);
        GLES31.GlGetIntegeri_v(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 1, work_grp_size, 1);
        GLES31.GlGetIntegeri_v(GLES31.GlMaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 2, work_grp_size, 2);
```